# AuthenticationManager.SignOut() fails IE only

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, owin.security

I am working with a strange credit card payment gateway where I send encrypted transaction info to the bank website. There the user enters the card info. I have set up two URLs with the bank (PaymentSuccess and PaymentFailure) where they return after payment processing. Payments and refunds, correct and incorrect all work as designed, except...

I am unable to log the user off after getting back from the bank: `AuthenticationManager.SignOut()` silently fails, no exception, no error just keeps the current user signed in **only in IE**. The same code works great in Chrome, Firefox, Opera, Safari.

The code, which is supposed to log a logged on user out of the system but doesn't:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult LogOff()
{
    //Response.Clear();
    AuthenticationManager.SignOut();
    Session["UserName"] = null;
    return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account");
}

private IAuthenticationManager AuthenticationManager
{
    get
    {
        return HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you are using MVC6?

Comment: I fail to see your code...

Comment: Edited to include the requested code and expected behavior.

Comment: have you fixed this issue?

Comment: Yes, I have. I cannot post the code because it is deemed too long.The gist AuthenticationManager.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
                    System.Runtime.Caching.MemoryCache.Default.Remove((string)Session["UserName"]);
                    ViewBag.AuthCount = System.Runtime.Caching.MemoryCache.Default.Where(kv => kv.Value.ToString() == "Auth").Count();